# How to map alphabet to integer in Python?

Tags: python

I want to get the distance between A and C is 2, what I could think of is using `ord`

```
ord('C') - ord('A')

#=>2
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: What's not elegant about using ord()?

Answer (score 4):

What is not elegant about that?

Maybe you could do

```
def get_character_distance(character):
  return ord(character.upper()) - ord('A')
```

to better describe what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

If you really don't want to use `ord`, you could look up the character's position in a string of all the letters in order - Python happens to provide exactly such a string (or, several of them containing different things) in the `string` module, and strings do have a method for finding the position of a character:

```
>>> string.ascii_uppercase.index('C')
2
```

But if efficiency is a concern, using `ord` is much better - it works in constant time, this does a linear search.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, that's about as good as it gets.

You may want to build a lookup of characters that you actually want instead of being dependent on `ord()`... and then have the lookup raise an exception, or default invalid characters...

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
lookup = dict( (ch, idx) for idx, ch in enumerate(ascii_uppercase) )
print 'distance is', lookup['C'] - lookup['A'] # 2
print 'distance is', abs(lookup['A'] - lookup['C']) # still return 2
print 'distance is', lookup['C'] - lookup['a'] # raises KeyError
print 'distance is', lookup['C'] - lookup.get('a', 0) # effectively returns lookup['C']
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try:

```
from string import ascii_letters as letters
def distance(char1,char2):
    return letters.index(char2) - letters.index(char1)
```

I still think `ord(char2)-ord(char1)` is way cooler.

Some technical perspective:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='letters.index("C") - letters.index("A")',setup="from string import ascii_letters as letters",number=10000000)
3.5703659057617188
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='ord("C") - ord("A")',setup="",number=10000000)
0.9403810501098633
```

Conclusion: `ord("C") - ord("A")` rocks!!